# Show that $\sqrt[n]{z}=\{|\sqrt[n]{z}|\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right)\zeta^{k}|k= 0,1,\ldots,n−1\}.$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that
$$\sqrt[n]{z}=\{ |\sqrt[n]{z}| \cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right) +i \sin\left( \frac{\theta}{n} \right) \right) \zeta^{k} \mid k= 0,1,\ldots,n−1\}.\tag{1}$$

My attempt:

Let $z=r(\cos{ \theta }+i\sin\theta )$ and let $w = \rho \left( cos{ \phi } + i \sin{ \phi } \right)$ and $\theta = arg\left(z\right)$.

Note by De Moivre's Formula for the polar representation of powers of

complex numbers,

$z^{n} = r^{n}\left( \cos{\theta n} + i\sin{\theta n} \right)$

Now to find $z^{n} = w$, we have,

$z^{n} = r^{n}\left( \cos{\theta n} + i\sin{\theta n} \right) = \rho \left( cos{ \phi} + i \sin{ \phi} \right) = w$.

Thus, we have $r^{n} = \rho$ and $\theta n = \phi +2 \pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbf{Z}$.

When we solve for $r$ and $\theta$,
$r= \sqrt[n]{\rho}$ and $\theta =\frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{n}$.

Therefore, $z= \sqrt[n]{\rho}\left( \cos{\frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{n}} + i\sin{\frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{n}} \right)$,

which is satisfied by all $k = \{0,1,2,...,n-1 \}$ and equivalent to (1).

Is there anyway that this can be improved?